# Vertical bitwise COUNT (sum of ones on the same position)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Is there any efficient way to do COUNT of ones on the same position in many variables? The count function should fill array with sum of ones in corresponding bit number. For example we have following three variables (I use 8-bit variables to make it simple):

```
uint8_t a = 0xF;  // 0000 1111
uint8_t b = 0x3C; // 0011 1100
uint8_t c = 0xF0; // 1111 0000

int result[8];

// some operations ...

count << result[0] << result[1] << .... // prints 1122 2211
```

I found many solutions for summing the ones in whole single variable, but not for the above problem.

Comment: Do you need a solution for N variables or just 3?

Comment: 256 lookup table containing an array of 8 0/1 bytes to add into accumulators?

Comment: I think 8*N  operations is the best you can get (up to a const)..

Comment: Or reduce it to `N` if using a lookup table as @MartinJames suggests. Anyway, there is no magical solution here.

Comment: How many is "many variables"? Posted code shows 3.  "prints 1122 2211" implies up to 9 - because `result[]` output has no spacing. If an array of `uint8_t`, should the maximum then be `size_t SIZE_MAX` as that is the largest array pass-able? or `INT_MAX` as that is the type of `result[]` Without further clarification, looks like 9 should be assumed.  Same question for "bit number" width.  Post shows 8 to make it simple, but what are the expectations for the answer.  Fix bit width? Variable bit width of 1 to 64?  more than 64?  Without further info, looks like fixed 8 should be assumed.

Comment: "*efficient*" in terms of what? Speed, simplicity, code size, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little code does exactly what you want. You can easily expand it to support N variables through a little lookup array. Notice the use of the double not operation. It is to drag the output to either be 0 or 1.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint8_t a = 0xF;  // 0000 1111
    uint8_t b = 0x3C; // 0011 1100
    uint8_t c = 0xF0; // 1111 0000

    unsigned result[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        unsigned mask = 1 << i;
        result[i] = !!(a & mask) + !!(b & mask) + !!(c & mask);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        cout << result[i];
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest writing out the result as soon as its calculated.  This would eliminate another `for-loop`, and you wouldn't need the array `result`

Comment: I assumed he'd want to store the individual results in a place. It can be easily changed to eliminate the array altogether and outputting the result as they are calculated, like you said.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for. Is there any SIMD operation that can do such thing in parallel?

Comment: @nosbor If you have access to SIMD then this would be much simpler. You basically blow the bit pattern into a wide vector(map the 8 bit input to a 64 bit 8bitx8 vector, each bit of input is assigned to the lowest bit of an element of the vector), then sum up the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Expand each `uint8_t` binary digit into a `uint32_t` hex digit and "add them up".  Good as long as not more than 15 per bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// See below for tighter code
uint32_t shift_nibble(uint8_t x) {
  uint32_t y = 0;
  uint32_t mask = 1;
  while (x) {
    if (x & 1) {
      y |= mask;
    }
    mask <<= 4;
    x >>= 1;
  }
  return y;
}

void PrintVerticalBitwiseCount(const  uint8_t *x, size_t size) {
  uint32_t y = 0;
  for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++) {
    y += shift_nibble(x[i]);
  }
  printf("%08lX\n", (unsigned long) y);
}

int main(void) {
  const uint8_t a[] = { 0xF, 0x3C,  0xF0 };
  PrintVerticalBitwiseCount(a, sizeof a/sizeof *a);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
11222211
```

---

A candidate faster `shift_nibble()`.  Put on your octal hat

```
uint32_t shift_nibble(uint8_t x) {
  uint32_t y;
  y  = UINT32_C(0x01010101) & (UINT32_C(0001010101) * (x & 0x55));
  y |= UINT32_C(0x10101010) & (UINT32_C(0010101010) * (x & 0xAA));
  return y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the fastest solution here, the only limitation to 15 is the issue.

Comment: @nosbor  As usual, the more tightly constrained the problem, the better  goals of speed/size/memory are met.  Could use `uint64_t` and go up to 255 perhaps.  But your "prints 1122 2211" implied 15 was all that was needed.

Answer (score 1):

As a template I suggest the function below in C++11. The returned list has the bit counts in the appropriate place for each bit, that is to say the least significant bit count is at position 0, the next most at position 1 etc. 
Hope this helps someone.

```
template<typename T>
std::list<long>
vertical_bit_sum(std::vector<T> items)
{
    size_t bits = sizeof(T) * 8;
    std::list<long> result;
    do
    {
        long count = 0;
        for ( T item : items)
        {
            count += (0x1 & (item >> (bits-1)));
        }

        result.push_front (count);
        --bits;
    }
    while( bits > 0);

    return result;
}

std::list<long> result= vertical_bit_sum<uint8_t>( { 0xF, 0x3C, 0xF0  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
uint64_t accum = 0;
uint64_t table[0x100] = {.. precomputed vals ...};
int count = 0xFF;
while(bytes_available()) {
  if(--count == 0) {
    count = 0xFF;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      result[i] = ((uint8_t*)&accum)[i];
    accum = 0;
  }
  accum += table[(uint8_t)get_next_byte()];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sheer speed, you can process 8 counts in parallel by keeping 8 bytes packed in a single 64 bits accumulator.

Initialize a lookup-table with 256 64-bit entries which are the original 8 bits expanded to bytes. (For instance, the entry `Lookup[0x17u]` maps to `0x0000000100010101ul`.)

Counting is just performed with

```
Acc+= Lookup[Byte];
```

You retrieve the individual counters by mapping an array of 8 bytes on the 64 bits.

You can perform the accumulation 256 times before overflow occurs; if you need more, accumulate in blocks of 256, and after a block has been processed, transfer the counts to larger accumulators.

If you need to accumulate no more than 16 times, 32 bit accumulators will suffice.

Answer (score -1):

Determining if there's a 1 at a particular position in a variable is much simpler than doing a normal population count.

```
bool hasOneAtPosition(int position, int target) {
    int mask = 1 << position;
    return (target & mask) != 0;
}
```

... Just call that on all your inputs and increment a counter every time it returns true. Simplez.

Comment: ... Pretty sure it is. It's got "Answer" written above it and everything.

If you think I've missed part of the question, perhaps tell me what you think I missed instead of leaving an unhelpful comment?

Comment: "*It's got "Answer" written above it ...*" Has it? Not for me.

Comment: Well, okay, "Answers" :P

Comment: But it doesn't answer the original question. It merely gives a function that can returns whether a bit is set in an int. It does not address an efficient way to count how many of that bit are set in a group of variables. Certainly introducing a function call for each variable does not seem to be very efficient.

Comment: Using `unsigned` avoids UB problems with shifting in to the sign bit.  Simplified:  `bool hasOneAtPosition(int position, unsigned target) { return (1U << position)  & target; }`